# Can't configure Ubuntu 14.04.3 to generate a warning when battery is low

Tags: battery

Can't configure Ubuntu 14.04.3 to generate a warning when battery is low. By the way, I do have packages libnotify-bin notify-osd installed.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall libnotify-bin notify-osd, using:

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install libnotify-bin notify-osd`.

This worked for me.

Comment: Tried this but still don't see an option to enable a low-battery warning. Do you have it? Could you attach a snapshot? Thanks.